# How can I use shared firestore instance on express?

Tags: typescript, firebase, express, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a Firebase Functions with Express app and I would like to use the Firestore instance on multiple controllers. So I created a simple service:

**./services/firebase.serivce.ts**

```
  admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
  const firestore = admin.firestore();
  export const db = firestore;
```

Then in my controller

**./controllers/test.ts**

```
import { db } from './../services/firebase.service';
...

const collection = db.collection('contacts');
const router = express.Router();

router.post('/', (req, res) => {
...
```

and the `app.js`

```
 import { TestController } from './controllers/test'
 ...

  app.use('/contact', TestController);
  export const api = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

But Im getting the error:

> The default Firebase app does not exist. Make sure you call initializeApp() before using any of the Firebase services.

And if I try to `initializeApp()` in all my controllers, I get a message saying that the app already exists.

What can I do to share the same instance for multiple files?

Comment: Try to change it to `const app = admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
  const firestore = app.firestore();
  export const db = firestore;` 

Does it work?

Comment: If you're trying to do this for performance reasons, you should know that `admin.firestore()` is not at all expensive to call more than once.  It returns the same thing every time.

Comment: @DougStevenson I tried your solution, I´ve called the initalizedApp() on the main index.ts, and the in my controller I tried to call admin.firebase(), but I get a error saying that `The default Firebase app does not exist`